# Mobile Sound Tracker Application Architecture

Tags: java, android, database, spring-boot, server

I have an assignment, but I can't seem to get my head around it. I've been tasked to create a mobile app on Android Studio using the microphone sensor to record audio (Parameters: Duration & frequency). The data/sample is then stored locally, perhaps using SQLite to store the id, date, time, location and sample. Let's say after 10 samples (this is where it starts to get confusing for me), the samples are bundled up and sent to the communication server which I believe OkHttp client is used in this case. The data gets sent to a local server (Apache?) and a website (Springboot) is used to retrieve the information and show the samples on Google Maps.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACAfW.jpg

Link to application architecture is above. I have no doubt it is wrong, but would love some insight on it please. Also, I very new to all of this so I'm sure there are a lot of gaps in my message above. If you have any questions please feel free to ask!

Technologies I've been recommended to use:

Local Server: Apache

Website: SpringBoot

Communication tool: OkHttp

Android application: Android Studio

Comment: Spring boot is not a website and apache is not an application server, are you sure those are the right way around? This isn't really something this site can answer, I guess you need to talk to whoever gave you this assignment to clear up your questions, since architecture is just a very broad overview of an idea, nothing that has a concrete solution

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, can't you build a website with Spring boot? The technologies listed were recommended by my colleague. I've asked before, but his reply was very abstract and I couldn't picture it in my head. I'll ask again though!

Comment: Spring boot itself is the technology to build a server backend, it can serve website content but you'll need to decide how it does that. E.g. Thymeleaf template based or serving a static angular/react/flutter/.. website that uses rest apis of your spring boot server. And Apache itself can be many things but without knowing what it should do I'd assume it's just a static webpage which is something you can't send data to. If you use apache with php you can have another backend (but why then spring?).  Or apache could be meant to be a proxy for the spring server but your picture is unclear to me